# Android Emulator Float Without border

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make my emulator looks like this

[image]

Currently my emulator looks like this

[image]

what do I do to achieve the first picture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**File -> Settings -> Tools -> Emulator ->** Uncheck **`Launch in a tool window`**, Click **`ok`**.
For me, restarting the IDE was required too.